# Вывод уникального текста

Tags: php

Доброе время суток, необходимо написать скрипт который будет продавать инвайты (текстовые), конечно скрипт обработки покупки я напишу сам, а вот как просто реализовать выдачу уникального текста из txt или бд не понимаю :(

Comment: @misc

    md5(microtime().$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

И у вас на руках уже относительно случайный хэш.

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.uniqid.php

А используя в качестве префикса любой хэш или часть хэша. Можно получать хорошие ключи.

```
$id = uniqid();
$good_id = substr(md5($id),0,10) . $id;
```